# Determining if a call to ICollection Count will result in iteration

Tags: c#, count, icollection

Suppose I want to access an object from a `Collection`, and I want to be sure
it doesn't iterate through the whole `Collection` just to determine the size.

How can I determine and control if a call to `Count` results in actually iterating though the collection?
(other than using my own implementation of `ICollection`) , in other words are there implementations that offer this?

```
public void PrintThreeNames(ICollection<string> names)
{
    //first I want to know if the collection has at least three elements.
    if (names != null && names.Count >= 3)
    {
        IEnumerator<string> enumerator = names.GetEnumerator();
        string value0 = enumerator.Current;
        enumerator.MoveNext();
        string value1 = enumerator.Current;
        enumerator.MoveNext();
        string value2 = enumerator.Current;
        //print values.
        Console.Writeline(value0 + value1 + value2);
    }
}
```

In response to the programmers hero question. I guess I can make a `IEnumerable<T>` collection add a million documents to it, and count it to see how fast a call to `Count` is as well.

I asked this question as I may choose using `IEnumerable` over `Collection`, as my collections are so large in numbers and data per item as well, that it will be a problem to return all of them at once.

However, I would like to know the disadvantages of `IEnumarable` as well, Joshua pointed about locking it is not a good idea, in another question.

Comment: I have checked the well known List<T> class as a frequently used implementation. documentation of Count method is: Gets the number of elements actually contained in the List<T>. Still don't know if it iterates here or not... (Allthough I can guess)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because ICollection exposes Count as a property, it should be safe to assume that it is very cheap to get its value (i.e. it should not iterate through the entire collection).

This is just a best practice surrounding properties - getting their values should be cheap - period.

If the operation is expensive, then it should be a method - e.g. Count().

Sure, somebody could certainly provide an expensive implementation of ICollection.Count - however then that person is not doing things right.

If calculating the number of elements is expensive, they should implement only IEnumerable - not ICollection.

Answer (score 2):

Are there implementations of `Count` that are relatively expensive? Probably, but they'll be rare; the .NET Framework classes are tuned for pretty good all-round efficiency.

Does it matter? Almost certainly not. Unless you're querying `Count` millions of times over collections with millions of elements, the difference is so small as to be irrelevant:

- 100 Million calls to `List<T>.Count` containing 1 million integers: 0.85s
- 100 Million calls to `HashSet<T>.Count()` containing 1 million integers: 1.45s

Answer (score 0):

Technically because ICollection is an interface you have no guarantee that it won't iterate through the collection.  The interface could be implemented anyway.